# The byte form of variables of various types after serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I was converting different variables of different types into byte arrays using the function shown below.

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        various_types a = default(current_type);
        byte[] bytearray = ObjectToByteArray(a);
        Console.WriteLine(bytearray);
    }
```

For **byte a = 0;**

```
0 1 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 1 0 0 0 11 83 121 115 116 101 109 46 66 121 116 101 1 0 0 0 7 109 95 118 97 108 117 101 0 2 0 11
```

For **byte a = 255;**

```
0 1 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 1 0 0 0 11 83 121 115 116 101 109 46 66 121 116 101 1 0 0 0 7 109 95 118 97 108 117 101 0 2 255 11
```

Different is only the byte next to the last one - the variable's value is stored there. The rest is identical. It is true for all other types as well; a set of identical bytes (around 50 it seems - 49 identical bytes for 'byte' type, 50 for 'int' type, 51 for 'ulong' type), then a few bytes that store the actual value, and one byte ending it (11 is the finishing byte for all types I checked).

What information is contained in the other bytes?

Comment: There is a lot more in your hex dump that has nothing to do with variable types.  BinaryFormatter adds a file header and includes the type declaration for the type and the field that stores the value.  More obvious when you use a decent hex viewer that also shows you the ascii text for the byte values.  A byte otherwise has a very simple representation, it only takes a byte.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. Where can I gather such knowledge (where do you know it from)? I cannot see anything of that sort on MSDN, nor does googling reveal it, at least at the first glance.

Comment: I reverse-engineered it by first wondering how BinaryFormatter was capable of detecting assembly versions and class changes, then looking at a hex dump like you did and reading the BinaryFormatter source code.  A web site like SO is a pretty decent way to avoid having to spend that kind of time.

Comment: @JohnSmith take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844.aspx. It's the spec for BinaryFormatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant said, the data is related to the inner workings of BinaryFormatter, rather than the variable itself. The variable itself takes as much as in its specification.

> There is a lot more in your hex dump that has nothing to do with variable types. BinaryFormatter adds a file header and includes the type declaration for the type and the field that stores the value. More obvious when you use a decent hex viewer that also shows you the ascii text for the byte values. A byte otherwise has a very simple representation, it only takes a byte.